# how to receive file in java(servlet/jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post

hi i am making communication protocol. on my web server i send one file with curl(in c# POST HTTP Request). this task is been successfully done. how should i receive this file with java on my web server i gone through [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2007/07/fileservlet.html#FileServletServingFromAbsolutePath). but its about file downloading. i just want to receive file with java.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help .. you have to provide multiprt form data .. http://www.journaldev.com/2122/servlet-3-file-upload-using-multipartconfig-annotation-and-part-interface

Answer (score 0):

Get InputStream from HttpServletRequest InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream(); and then read bytes from it till EOS